# Lucene Search Manager

Tags: search, lucene

I'm designing a new search based web application in lucene. I've to share and re-open the IndexSearcher across multiple Threads. I've read about the SearcherManager in the api document. I'm not able to understand the uses of it. How should I share the SearcherManager across MultipleThreads.

Answer (score 3):

see [here](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/09/lucenes-searchermanager-simplifies.html) for an article with code samples from one of the Lucene commiters